# Menu highlight based on url pattern

Tags: php, jquery

I have a sidebar menu that is created if a specific tag is found in a category. For example

- Apples
- Oranges

When clicked, the URL pattern would be as below:

> /category/?tag=apples

The code that renders the menu is as below:

```
       <?php if ( $term->slug == 'apples' ) {?>
        <section class="item">
        <h4><a href="<?php $category_id = get_query_var('cat'); 
echo get_category_link( $category_id );?>?tag=apples"> Apples</a>
    </h4></section>

         <?php } if ( $term->slug == 'oranges') {?>
         <section class="item">
        <h4><a href="<?php $category_id = get_query_var('cat'); 
echo get_category_link( $category_id );?>?tag=oranges"> Oranges</a>
    </h4></section>
        <? } ?>
        <?php } } ?>
```

I'm having a difficult time to highlight "Apples" with a red background when that is the active URL pattern, and the same with Oranges having an orange background.

I have tried various Jquery fiddle examples that works perfectly on fiddle, but not when i implement them. Most are for static html pages which is easier to do.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably something you should put in a loop, but an example for your `apples` section:

```
<section class="item <?php echo ($term->slug === $_GET('tag')) ? 'active' : '';">
    <h4><a href="<?php $category_id = get_query_var('cat'); 
          echo get_category_link( $category_id );?>?tag=apples"> Apples</a>
  </h4></section>
```

Note that I have added an `active` class to the section element so that you can style that (or its children) differently.

Answer (score 0):

Why not verify the $_GET variable and then highlight the active URL ?

```
if ($_GET['tag'] == 'apples')
    echo ''; //Highlight : ON, with CSS
else
    echo ''; //Highlight : OFF
```

Same goes for "oranges".

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get something working with this. I now only need to add an array of words instead of just 'apples',  is it possible to list them all. For example:  == 'apples','oranges',  etc..

Comment: You can try with php's in_array() function, see here : http://ch2.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged it with jQuery, you can solve it on the client side:

```
function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : 
           decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

$(function(){

    var tag = getParameterByName('tag');

    if(tag){

        $('h4').filter(function(){
            return $(this).text().toLowerCase() === tag;
        }).css({ color: 'red' });
    }

});
```

Allthough I suggest you solve it directly on the server using PHP. Just an alternative.